# How to handle well-known english acronyms and names for an abstract in the local language?

Tags: thesis, language, abstract, translations

I have to provide a translated version of my abstract in my local country language. There are some concepts / names / acronyms that are also in my country language mostly used in english, for instance, Semantic Web. I think calling it in my local language does not make much sense because it is known under that term. What is the common way to handle this? Also if I want to abbreviate it with (SW). Thanks for your help!

Comment: write "for instance, Semantic Web (ST)" so you can then use ST and it will refer to Semantic Web.
I still wonder why ST and not SW or SeW.

Comment: Why do you feel the need for the abbreviation?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer to this probably depends a bit on why you need the translated abstract, and who it's for. If you're translating it for the benefit of a class of school children (say), the situation is different from if you're translating it for a group of professionals who can be expected to already be familiar with the English terminology.

Can you find other documents written in your native language on this/similar topics? How do they deal with this issue? If it is common to just use the English term, then I would think it's appropriate to also do so in your 'translation'.

Note that you are producing a 'translation', not a 'transliteration'. If appropriate, you can add a sentence/footnote/similar to the translated version to clarify the issue, e.g. to say "A literal translation of this term would be XYZ, but we will use the English term in this document".